# How to find pandas dataframe rows pair which occur only within 1 hour timeframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Here is how my data looks:

```
         TagID                       PlazaEntryTime                         PlazaID
     0   1001                     9/29/19 9:31:06 PM                         1420
     1   2002                     10/29/19 9:31:06 PM                        1421
     2   1001                     9/29/19 9:49:06 PM                         1550
     3   2004                     12/29/19 9:31:06 PM                        1422
     4   1001                     9/29/19 11:49:06 PM                        1550
```

I want to display all the pair of rows where tagIDs have both plazaIDS 1420 and 1550, and the pair should be within 1 hour of time.

So for example in the above data, only row0 and row2 should be printed as this pair is within 1 hour of time and row4 should not be printed as row4 time is more than 1 hour ahead in time when compared with row0.

Comment: how large is your dataFrame?

Comment: It has around 500978 rows × 50 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

the idea is to sort your data frame filter by the two codes and then apply `diff()` which subtracts from the nth element on a given axis. the defautl is 1.

we use `np.timedelta` to return the hourly difference to the datetime column.

finally we use `fillna` so we can get the pair of values.

```
import numpy as np
s = df.sort_values(["TagID", "PlazaID", "PlazaEntryTime"]).loc[
    df["PlazaID"].isin([1420, 1550])
].groupby("TagID")["PlazaEntryTime"].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, "h")
```

---

```
print(df.loc[s[s.fillna(0) < 1].index])

   TagID      PlazaEntryTime  PlazaID
0   1001 2019-09-29 21:31:06     1420
2   1001 2019-09-29 21:49:06     1550
```